# Map Multilist field with objects of different templates

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a multilist field on an item that can contain items from different templates. I was wondering if there was any way to map this field in such a way that the objects are mapped to the correct model based on their template. So for example:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string FullName {get; set;}
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....")]
public class Professor
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public string Prefix {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string FullName
    {
        return string.format("{0} {1} {2}", Prefix, FirstName, LastName)
    }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....")]
public class Student
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string FullName
    {
        return string.format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName)
    }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....")]
public class ClassSession
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public IEnumerable<IPerson> Participants {get; set;}
}
```

In this instance I'd like the `Participants` property to contain `Student` and `Professor` objects since they implement the `Fullname` property differently.

Answer (score 6):

You can use infer types in Glass.mapper, Inferred types allows you to load a more specific type based on the template of the item being loaded. :

```cs
public interface IPerson
{
    string FullName {get; set;}
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....", AutoMap = true)]
public class Professor : IPerson
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public string Prefix {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string FullName
    {
        return string.format("{0} {1} {2}", Prefix, FirstName, LastName)
    }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....", AutoMap = true)]
public class Student : IPerson
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    [SitecoreField]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public string FullName
    {
        return string.format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName)
    }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId="....", AutoMap = true)]
public class ClassSession
{
    [SitecoreField(Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.InferType)]
    public IEnumerable<IPerson> Participants {get; set;}
}
```

Notice that i added `AutoMap = true` in your classes atrributes, and changed your multilist property attribute to be like:

`[SitecoreField(Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.InferType)]`

For more details, go to mike tutorials here:
http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial17/tutorial17.html

**Edit**:

You need to include your assembly in configurations loader, find the GlassMapperScCustom class in your solution. You should then update the GlassLoaders method:

```cs
public static IConfigurationLoader[] GlassLoaders()
    {
        var attributes = new AttributeConfigurationLoader("Your assembly name");

        return new IConfigurationLoader[] {attributes };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. This looks exactly like what I want, unfortunately it is not working. The items are still getting mapped as `IPersonProxy` and the fields are not populated correctly.

Comment: I just updated my answer, there is one last step you need to do

Comment: I'm now getting "You can not have duplicate mappings for properties. Property Name: Name  Type: Name" on this line in `GlassMapperSc`: `context.Load(GlassMapperScCustom.GlassLoaders());`

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that, i just checked the code causing this exception, and it seems there are some duplicate properties in one of your models.

Line 81: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper/Configuration/AbstractTypeConfiguration.cs

Comment: What exactly does that mean? The same Sitecore field is being mapped to two different properties? If so I do that quite often in the case of Multilist fields so that I can use the same models for doing Sitecore Search queries. I map the raw value to `IEnumerable<ID>` and then also have a property for `IEnumerable<Model>`

Comment: I'm not sure, but to figure that out, include glass mapper source code in your project and debug that function 'AddProperty' to know exactly what went wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60240/discussion-between-ahmed-okour-and-kyle).